# How to get current item in Django

Tags: django

In my Django project I have catalog of products, there is how its look like in models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
   category = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   description = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)

class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

This is product detail view.

```
def ProductDetailView(request, pk):
        productdetail = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'product/detail.html', {'productdetail':productdetail})
```

And this is urls.py for product detail view:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ProductDetailView, name='detail'),
```

Now I need to add an order button on product detail page. When user click on this button, the data with the order have to save to the database, so i made a new model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
   order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
   customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

All datas for this model i take from the form, but i don't know how to get current product field. I will be thankful if you will help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add current item ID to HTML (by template tags). For example as hidden form field:

```
<input id="id_current_item_id" name="current_item_id" type="hidden"
    value="{{ current_item.id }}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input name="prouct_id" id="id_product" type="hidden" value="{{product.id}}">
```

and submit the order form. You will get product id in view.